# Is it possible to use node mailer to send mails in ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, nodemailer

I am trying to integrate node mailer with ionic project to send email without user interference . But as I added node mailer js using npm and used it in controller, it is giving following error.

> Error: Module name "nodemailer" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Answer (score 0):

Node Mailer can not be used to send email in ionic app. We need to have node to load the module node mailer using the require().

http://www.bossable.com/1910/angularjs-nodemailer-contact-form/

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:** No, node mailer is used at the Server end to send emails, cause it runs through *Node.JS*. But the Ionic App is a Hybrid App which runs in mobile device(Android/iOS) as simple *JS/HTML/CSS*. Thus, one can not run node modules in an Ionic APP.

**Solution:** You need to use email composer plugin for Apache Cordova to send emails via your ionic app.